# $\sqrt n < n!^\frac1n\ \forall \ n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, natural-numbers

Prove the following:

#1} $\frac12 < \frac1{3n+1} + \frac1{3n+2} + … + \frac1{5n+1} < \frac23$

#2}  $\sqrt n < n!^\frac1n \ \forall\  n>2$

Attempt (i) to #1}

Since $\frac{2n+1}{5n+1} < \frac1{3n+1} + \frac1{3n+2} + … + \frac1{5n+1} < \frac{2n+1}{3n+1}$

$ \implies \frac13 < \frac1{3n+1} + \frac1{3n+2} + … + \frac1{5n+1} < 1.$

Attempt (ii) to #1}
Since A.M.≥ H.M.

By some calculations, I got  $\frac1{3n+1} + \frac1{3n+2} + … + \frac1{5n+1} > \frac25 $

But, from either of the attempts nothing has proved.

And for #2} i have no idea how to get that. Had tried to use A.M.≥G.M.≥H.M.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions on a single post

Comment: I will take care of this.

Comment: Note $\sqrt 2= (2!)^{1/2}.$

Comment: The second one is a very standard result.What are the mods doing?

Answer (score 10):

I will show that $n^n<(n!)^2$. Note that that's not true for all $n\in \mathbb N$ as mentioned in the question. That's only true for $n>2$.

Now, note that for any integer $x$ which satisfies $1<x<n$, we have $(x-1)>0$ and $(x-n)<0$, which together gives $(x-1)(x-n)<0$ which implies $n< x\cdot (n-x+1)$. Also, for $x=1$ or $x=n$, we have $n\leq x\cdot (n-x+1)$.

Put $x=1,2,3,\dots ,n$ to get
\begin{align*}
&n\leq 1\cdot n\\
&n<2\cdot (n-1)\\
&n<3\cdot (n-2)\\
&\dots\\
&\dots\\
&\dots\\
&n\leq n\cdot 1
\end{align*}
Multiply these equations to get $n^n<(n!)^2$

This completes the proof.

Comment: thanks.. can you please give me hints for the first one?

Comment: @JINENDRA Oh! There was that as well? I didn't notice. Wait.

Comment: @JINENDRA If the source of these problems is what I think it is, then https://www.ctanujit.org/uploads/2/5/3/9/25393293/tomato_subjective_solutions.pdf might help you.

Comment: @JINENDRA About the first problem, I'm not quite sure, but try the standard approach of integrating $f(x)=\frac 1 x$ from $x=3n+1$ to $x=5n+1$. I think, that will help.

Comment: It might be better to write $n \le  x \cdot (n-x+1)$ unconditionally  for all $x$ such that $1 \le x \le n$  and that as soon as $n \gt 2$, there exists $y$ such that $1 \lt y \lt n$, which is enough to obtain the strict inequality after the multiplications.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof by induction
of the second inequality.

Suppose
$n^n < (n!)^2$
and
$(n+1)^{n+1} \ge ((n+1)!)^2$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
(n+1)^{n+1}
&\ge ((n+1)!)^2\\
&=(n!)^2(n+1)^2\\
&\gt n^n(n+1)^2\\
\text{so}\\
(n+1)^{n-1}
&\gt n^n\\
\text{or}\\
(1+\frac1{n})^n
&\gt n\\
\end{array}
$

which is false for
$n \ge 3$
since
$(1+\frac1{n})^n
\lt e
\lt 3
$.

Therefore
$n^n < (n!)^2$
and
$n \ge 3$
implies
$(n+1)^{n+1} \lt ((n+1)!)^2$.

Since
$3^3
=27
\lt 36
=(3!)^2
$,
$n^n < (n!)^2$
for $n \ge 3$.

You can also argue that
$(n+1)^{n-1}
\gt n^n
$
implies
$(n+1)^{1/n}
\gt n^{1/(n-1)}
$
which is false for
$n \ge 2$
since
$f(x)
=(x+1)^{1/x}
$
is decreasing for
$x \ge 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I can show that
the first sum is between
$\dfrac{40}{81}$
and
$\dfrac{44}{81}+\dfrac{25}{81n}
\lt\dfrac23$,
so this is not quite the
lower bound.

$\begin{array}\\
s(n)
&=\sum_{k=3n+1}^{5n+1} \dfrac1{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \dfrac1{3n+k}\\
&=\dfrac1{3n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \dfrac1{1+k/(3n)}\\
&\lt\dfrac1{3n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} (1-k/(3n)+k^2/(3n)^2)
\qquad\dfrac1{1+x} \lt 1-x+x^2\\
&=\dfrac{2n+1}{3n}-\dfrac1{3n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\dfrac{k}{3n}+\dfrac1{3n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\dfrac{k^2}{9n^2}\\
&=\dfrac23+\dfrac1{3n}-\dfrac1{9n^2}\dfrac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{2}+\dfrac1{27n^3}\dfrac{(2n+1)(2n+2)(4n+3)}{6}\\
&=\dfrac23+\dfrac1{3n}-\dfrac1{9n^2}(2n+1)(n+1)+\dfrac1{81n^3}(2n+1)(n+1)(4n+3)\\
&=\dfrac{44}{81}+\dfrac1{27 n^3} + \dfrac{4}{81 n^2} + \dfrac{2}{9 n}\\
&\lt\dfrac{44}{81}+\dfrac{25}{81n}
\qquad\text{for } n \ge 2\\
&\lt \dfrac23
\qquad\text{for } n \ge 3
\quad(\dfrac23-\dfrac{44}{81}=\dfrac{10}{81})\\
 \end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
s(n)
&=\sum_{k=3n+1}^{5n+1} \dfrac1{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \dfrac1{3n+k}\\
&=\dfrac1{3n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \dfrac1{1+k/(3n)}\\
&\gt\dfrac1{3n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} (1-k/(3n)+k^2/(3n)^2-k^3/(3n)^3)
\qquad\dfrac1{1+x} \gt 1-x+x^2-x^3\\
&=\dfrac{2n+1}{3n}-\dfrac1{3n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\dfrac{k}{3n}+\dfrac1{3n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\dfrac{k^2}{9n^2}-\dfrac1{3n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\dfrac{k^3}{27n^3}\\
&=\dfrac23+\dfrac1{3n}-\dfrac1{9n^2}\dfrac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{2}+\dfrac1{27n^3}\dfrac{(2n+1)(2n+2)(4n+3)}{6}-\dfrac1{81n^4}\dfrac{(2n+1)^2(2n+2)^2}{4}\\
&=\dfrac23+\dfrac1{3n}-\dfrac1{9n^2}(2n+1)(n+1)+\dfrac1{81n^3}(2n+1)(n+1)(4n+3)-\dfrac1{81n^4}(2n+1)^2(n+1)^2\\
&=\dfrac{40}{81}-\dfrac1{81 n^4} -\dfrac1{27 n^3} - \dfrac1{9 n^2} + \dfrac{2}{27 n} \\
 \end{array}
$

So not quite $\dfrac12$.

If I used
$\dfrac1{1+x} \gt 1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5
$,
the bound might be improved.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final answer.

The sum is
$\ln(5/3)+\dfrac{3}{5n}+O(n^{-2})
\approx 0.5108
$

In general,
$\sum_{k=un+1}^{vn+1} \dfrac1{k}
=\ln(v/u)+\dfrac{u}{vn}+O(n^{-2})
$.

$\begin{array}\\
s(n)
&=\sum_{k=3n+1}^{5n+1} \dfrac1{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \dfrac1{3n+k}\\
&=\dfrac1{3n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \dfrac1{1+k/(3n)}\\
&=\dfrac1{3n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^mk^m}{3^mn^m}\\
&=\dfrac1{3n}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^m}{3^mn^m}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} k^m\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^m}{3^{m+1}n^{m+1}}
\left(\dfrac{(2n+1)^{m+1}}{m+1}+\dfrac{(2n+1)^m}{2}+O(n^{m-1}) \right)\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^m}{3^{m+1}n^{m+1}}
\left(\dfrac{(2n)^{m+1}+(m+1)(2n)^{m}+O(n^{m-1})}{m+1}+\dfrac{(2n)^m+O(n^{m-1})}{2}+O(n^{m-1}) \right)\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^m}{3^{m+1}}
\left(\dfrac{(2)^{m+1}+(m+1)(2^m/n+O(n^{-2}))}{m+1}+\dfrac{2^m/n+O(n^{-2})}{2}+O(n^{-2}) \right)\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^m}{3^{m+1}}
\left(\dfrac{2^{m+1}}{m+1}+\dfrac1{n}\left( 2^m+\dfrac{2^m}{2}\right)+O(n^{-2}) \right)\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^m(2/3)^{m+1}}{m+1}+\dfrac1{n}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{m}(2/3)^m+O(n^{-2}) \\
&=\ln(5/3)+\dfrac{3}{5n}+O(n^{-2})\\
&\approx 0.5108\\
\end{array}
$