# Which grows faster $n!$ or $n^{\sqrt{n}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, computer-science, computational-complexity

From graph it can be easily seen that $n!$ grows faster that $n^{\sqrt{n}}$. Also wolfram alpha says that $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{n^{\sqrt{n}}}{n!}\right)=0$. I'd appreciate if anyone could explain how, being a complete noob I don't know how to compute the limit of the above function.

I also tried taking log of both the functions and then solving it through PMI, but no luck.

Comment: Take logarithms and use Stirling approximation in its simplest form.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici can you please explain?

Comment: Intuitively, $n!$ is a product of much more factors than $n^{\sqrt{n}}$ and they both have the same largest factor ($n$).  So $n!$ will quickly outgrow $n^{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: Note that $n!\ge (n/2)^{n/2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Taking logarithm makes things simpler:

$$
\log n!=\sum_{1\le k\le n}\log k>\sum_{1\le k\le n}\int_{k-1}^k\log t\mathrm dt=\int_0^n\log t\mathrm dt=n\log n-n
$$

Since $n\log n$ grows significantly faster than $n$ and $\sqrt n\log n$, we conclude $n!$ grows much faster than $n^{\sqrt n\log n}$, making that limit zero.

Comment: can you please explain how did you reach that conclusion? I've been trying to figure it out my own, but couldn't. I'd appreciate if you could help

Comment: @kiranpradeep What are you referring to for "that conclusion"?

Comment: Even simpler, just use $n!\ge (n/2)^{n/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way to see that these kind of limits are true is to use [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) which says
$$n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n$$
So,
$$\left(\frac{n^{\sqrt{n}}}{n!}\right)\sim\left(\frac{n^{\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n}\right)=n^{\sqrt n-n-\frac 12}e^n(2\pi)^{-1}=(2\pi)^{-1}\frac{e^n}{n^{n-\sqrt n+\frac 12}}$$
which is approximately $\frac{e^n}{n^n}$ for large $n$.

So, the limit is $0$.

---

As mark Viola pointed out, an easier way is to use $n!\ge \left(\frac n2\right)^{n/2}$. This can be derived easily from the fact that [$\left(n!\right)^2\ge n^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4192760/943723).

Comment: Application of Stirling's formula is overkill.  Just use $n!\ge (n/2)^{n/2}$.

Comment: @MarkViola yes, that works better for this problem. But, in general, whenever we want to intuitively understand a limit with powers and factorials of $n$, Stirling's Approximation is often a very useful tthing.

Comment: Actually, the inequality comes directly from $(2n)!\ge n^n$.